# How to Translate SQL Subquery to Linq?

Tags: sql, linq, subquery

I need to translate this query to Linq

```
SELECT m.Nombre, m.LugarSalida, m.FechaHorarioComienzo
FROM Maraton m 
WHERE m.FechaHorarioComienzo >= GETDATE()
  AND (m.MaxParticipantes + m.ParticipantesEnEspera) >
   (SELECT COUNT(*) as "Total de participantes"
    FROM ResultadoMaratonParticipante rm
    where rm.IdMaraton = m.IdMaraton
    GROUP BY rm.IdMaraton)
```

This contains a subquery, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Note: full code is next

PW3_20152C_TP2_MaratonesEntities3 context = new PW3_20152C_TP2_MaratonesEntities3();

```
    //Obtengo el listado de maratones
    DateTime hoy = DateTime.Now;
    List<Maraton> qm = (from m in context.Maraton
                       where m.FechaHorarioComienzo >= DateTime.Now
                         && (m.MaxParticipantes + m.ParticipantesEnEspera) >
                           (from rm in context.ResultadoMaratonParticipante
                            where rm.IdMaraton = m.IdMaraton // Cannot convert query expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type  TPFinalWeb3 

                            select rm).Count()
                       select m).ToList();
```

Comment: First of all, you can remove the GROUP BY from the sub-query. (Will only return count for one IdMaraton.) No need for that column alias either.

Comment: What kind of LINQ? And which navigation properties do you have? You may not need any subquery (in LINQ) at all.

Comment: Hi to everyone! I'm new in this language. 
In short , I need to show in a table all available for runs marathons . This depends on the date exceeds the present day and that the number of runners does not exceed the total amount available to brokers ( for this reason did the subquery , since this data is obtained by counting the number of people enrolled in each race ) . Is this reasoning correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side by side

**SQL**

```
SELECT m.Nombre, m.LugarSalida, m.FechaHorarioComienzo
FROM Maraton m 
WHERE m.FechaHorarioComienzo >= GETDATE()
  AND (m.MaxParticipantes + m.ParticipantesEnEspera) >
   (SELECT COUNT(*) as "Total de participantes"
    FROM ResultadoMaratonParticipante rm
    where rm.IdMaraton = m.IdMaraton)
```

**LINQ**

```
from m in db.Maraton
where m.FechaHorarioComienzo >= DateTime.Now
  && (m.MaxParticipantes + m.ParticipantesEnEspera) >
    (from rm in db.ResultadoMaratonParticipante
     where rm.IdMaraton == m.IdMaraton
     select rm).Count()
select new { m.Nombre, m.LugarSalida, m.FechaHorarioComienzo }
```

Comment: Ivan, thanks! 
I'm new in this, sorry. I want to show  the content of this query in a Data Grid. I posted the code in the previous question and I commented the error next to line.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Microsource The code I posted had a bug in the line you are getting error - operator `=` instead of `==` (see the corrected answer). Feel free to comment the answers if you find problems like this, but don't copy them to the question, because that makes it a different question and hence invalidates the existing answers.

Comment: Ivan, thanks a lot! It's work!

Note: I changed the last line for: select new{ m.Nombre, m.LugarSalida, m.FechaHorarioComienzo }

Comment: @Microsource Yeah, another bug - usually happening when writing something in notepad :-) Corrected the answer. Cheers.